# MongoDB only return document where user from other document does not match field

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

JavaScript:

```
exports.userWithoutProject = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let benchUser = [];
    const project = await Project.find({})
    const users = await User.find({}, {
      email: 1,
      _id: 0
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < project.length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < project[j].seats.length; k++) {
          if (users[i].email !== project[j].seats[k].employee && project[j].seats[k].employee === undefined) {
            benchUser.push(users[i].email)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const uniq = [...new Set(benchUser)];

    return res.json({
      users: uniq
    })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

Users:

```
[{ 
   email: 'user1@email.com',
 }, { 
   email: 'user2@email.com',
 }, {
   email: 'user3@email.com' 
 }]
```

Projects (Array of objects):

```
{ _id: 5cc2dd2eb3eea7004c9a7240,
  name: 'Project One',
  description:
   'Lorem Ipsum',
  start: '2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z',
  end: '2019-12-31T09:45:00.000Z',
  seats:
   [ 
     { 
       skills: [Array],
       _id: 5cc2e3cab3eea7004c9a724a,
       start: '2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z',
       end: '2019-12-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       potentialExtension: '2020-06-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       role: 'Dev',
       approved: true,
       workload: 10,
       employee: 'user1@email.com' 
     },
     { 
       skills: [Array],
       _id: 5cc2e3cab3eea7004c9a7241,
       start: '2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z',
       end: '2019-12-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       potentialExtension: '2020-06-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       role: 'PM',
       approved: true,
       workload: 20,
       employee: 'user3@email.com' 
     }
   ]
}
```

My goal:

I want to get all users returned, that do not have a project seat.

I have multiple projects and each project has a `seat` where the users email is written in the `employee` field. So I have to go through all projects and also loop through each project seat to check if my user matches or not.

My approach from above returns me `user2@email.com` which is correct but also `user1@email.com` which isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let users = [{ 
 email: 'user1@email.com',
}, { 
 email: 'user2@email.com',
}, {
 email: 'user3@email.com' 
}];

let projects = [{ _id: '5cc2dd2eb3eea7004c9a7240',
  name: 'Project One',
  description:
   'Lorem Ipsum',
  start: '2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z',
  end: '2019-12-31T09:45:00.000Z',
  seats:
   [ 
     { 
       skills: [Array],
       _id: '5cc2e3cab3eea7004c9a724a',
       start: '2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z',
       end: '2019-12-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       potentialExtension: '2020-06-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       role: 'Dev',
       approved: true,
       workload: 10,
       employee: 'user1@email.com' 
     },
     { 
       skills: [Array],
       _id: '5cc2e3cab3eea7004c9a7241',
       start: '2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z',
       end: '2019-12-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       potentialExtension: '2020-06-31T09:45:00.000Z',
       role: 'PM',
       approved: true,
       workload: 20,
       employee: 'user3@email.com' 
     }
   ]
}];

let projectUsers = new Set();
projects.forEach(({seats}) => {
 seats.forEach(({employee}) => projectUsers.add(employee));
});

let out = users.filter(({email}) => !Array.from(projectUsers).includes(email));
console.log(out)
```